# How to execute css media query?

Tags: html, css

1. html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./test.css">
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <div class="background">        
            <div class="logo"></div>
            <div class="imgboxd">
                <img src="../img/sec1.png" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="boxss"></div>
        </div> 
    </header>

</body>
</html>
```

2. css

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

header {
    width: 100%;
    height: 750px;
    background-color: #0D1430;
    position: absolute;
}

.logo {
    width: 54px;
    height: 68px;
    background: url("../img/logo.png") no-repeat center/cover;
    margin: 60px auto 20px;
}

header .background .imgboxd {
    text-align: center;
}


header .background .imgboxd img {
    width: 650px;
    height: 500px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    header {
        width: 100%;
        height: 50%;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        border: 5px solid yellow;
    }

    .background {
        width: 100%;
    }

    header .imgboxd img {
        width: 100px;
        height: 100px;
    }

    .boxss {

        position: absolute;

        left: 50%;
        top: 50%;

        transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
        width: 50%;
        height: 30%;
        border: 2px solid red;


    }
}
```

I don't know why css-mediaquery does't working.

.imgbox tag doesn't work only in (max-width: 768px)

I know that under line code work in prority.

What should I do?

1.
I input img tag(html tag) in imgboxd(html tag)

2.

1. use imgboxd only,
2. input img link in imgboxd (css)

But, 2 kinds method does not working

Comment: You have to be more specific, how does it not work? how is it supposed to work? Maybe this [mdn doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) cna help you

Comment: Removed the javascript tag since all this seems solvable with just html and css

Comment: I always found to use media query the other. First declaration (all declaration involved in media query) is for small screen. Next you make media min-width:768px, and you put class which change at 768 and bigger

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

### Use the same selector in your media query

I noticed you didn't use the same CSS selector for the image inside your media query.

What you wrote outside the media query was this:
`header .background .imgboxd img`

In your media query in the question you have this:
`header .imgboxd img`

But you have to use the same selector both times.
Also see [CSS Specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity)

See working snippet below:

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

header {
    width: 100%;
    height: 750px;
    background-color: #0D1430;
    position: absolute;
}

.logo {
    width: 54px;
    height: 68px;
    background: url("https://picsum.photos/54/68") no-repeat center/cover;
    margin: 60px auto 20px;
}

header .background .imgboxd {
    text-align: center;
}


header .background .imgboxd img {
    width: 650px;
    height: 500px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    header {
        width: 100%;
        height: 50%;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        border: 5px solid yellow;
    }

    .background {
        width: 100%;
    }

    header .background .imgboxd img {
        width: 100px;
        height: 100px;
    }

    .boxss {

        position: absolute;

        left: 50%;
        top: 50%;

        transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
        width: 50%;
        height: 30%;
        border: 2px solid red;


    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <div class="background">        
            <div class="logo"></div>
            <div class="imgboxd">
                <img src="https://picsum.photos/seed/so/1200/960" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="boxss">Example text</div>
        </div> 
    </header>

</body>
</html>
```